# How to enable single selection in check box in custom list view in android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have a list view.In the row of list view there is 4 text view and a check box.
In the text view text set from a Array list.In list view there is more the 20 row.
And this is my problem how to enable single selection in check box.
At a time i want only a single check box
if i check a check box the other is checked it automatically unchecked how it possible.
please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this link http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-checkboxes-to-custom-listview-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `youcheckbox.setchecked(false)` for **unchecking** any `checkbox`. on any `checkbox` click call this method for other clicked `checkboxes`

or use `radioboxes`

Comment: i have only a single check box and i set it into row of custom list view

Comment: ok. in your list view adapter you could know which checkbox in which row is clicked. So uncheck all other checkboxes.

Comment: i m not understand how it posible.in every row only single check box set

Comment: i assume you are using any adapters to populate the list view.., right?